# Taylor expansion of exponential of a Lie derivative

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, differential-equations, na.numerical-analysis

In [this paper](https://www.ams.org/mcom/2008-77-264/S0025-5718-08-02101-7/) on page 8 the author claims that the Taylor expansion for the expression $e^{tD_V}$ where $D_V$ is the Lie derivative with respect to a vector field $V$ (defined by $(D_VG)(x) = \frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0}V(\phi^t_V(x))$ and $\phi^t_V(x)$ is the flow of the differential equation $\dot{\psi} = V(\psi)$ looks like this

$$e^{tD_V} = I +tD_V +t^2\int_0^1(1-\theta)e^{\theta t D_V}D_V^2 d\theta $$

I can't wrap my head around the remainder term. Shouldn't it be of third oder in $D_V$ because the integrand involves the third derivative of the exponential? I was thinking that a change of variables is performed but it didn't work. A related question might be [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/309170/exponential-map-lie-derivative-in-variation-for-constant-formula-for-ode) which is concerned with the same paper but ask a different question, still.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing something, but it seems to me you're overthinking this. Since
$$
\int_{0}^{1} d\theta (1-\theta ) \theta^{n} = \frac{1}{n+1} -\frac{1}{n+2} = \frac{n!}{(n+2)!}
$$
the third term in your expression is
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{t^{n+2} D_V^{n+2} }{n!} \frac{n!}{(n+2)!}
= \sum_{n=2}^{\infty } \frac{t^n D_V^n }{n!}
$$
exactly as it should be.

Comment: It's also, I believe, the integral remainder formula for the first order Taylor polynomial of $f(x) = e^x$, evaluated at $x = tD_V$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Explicit_formulas_for_the_remainder

Comment: So I figured that the integral led my onto a false lead because I thought this would be the integral formula for the remainder and I unsuccessfully tried to fit in the "false" order of $D_V$.